# MVVMCross Vee Three Solution

Tags: mvvmcross

This could be a really dumb question, but I just can't seem to open the v3 solution file.

I experienced something similar on the vNext, but after an hour or so it resolved itself and seem to set itself up ok for future access. This v3 has been running overnight and still not loaded.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you need to supply more information - what operating system are you on? Which development environment(s)? Which SDKs do you have installed?

V3 is currently being developed in Xamarin Studio (v4.0.2) on the Mac for iOS and on a custom build of Xamarin iOS and Droid plugged into VS2012 Ultimate on the PC - with WP7.1 and WP8 SDKs both installed, and with resharper (and a smattering of other code too)

I've checked in a lot of code in the last 24 hours - so it's worth getting the latest again from source control and seeing if that helps.

If it doesn't then is there any more information published to the output windows about what is going wrong? I've personally had a lot of problems and a lot of wasted time with the Xamarin plugins in VS2012 - the activation modules are a nightmare (which is why I have a custom build currently installed)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stuart. I'm running on a Mac with Parallels with Windows 8. Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and WP8 SDKs. Latest Resharper too. I've pulled the latest code and it just sits at the Preparing Solution stage within VS. There's no output to help either. I think what I'll try and do tonight is recreate the solution file locally and see where I get to.

Comment: You don't have VSMonoTouch still installed, do you? If not, then maybe just leave it to open... it will eventually...

Comment: I think like you say it's the new Xamarin plugin. It's validating then restarting VS after adding each project.